# Почему увеличивается размер базы данных при обновлении таблицы в MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Почему увеличивается размер базы данных при обновлении таблицы в MSSQL?

Хочу понять на примере, чтобы понимать как прогнозировать объем необходимый серверу.

Есть база db1 в MSSQL 2019 с Recovery Mode - Simple
В базе единственная таблица с 100 миллинов строк и с несколькими столбцами. Данные таблицы сжаты с помощью page compression. В несжатом виде таблица занимает 30ГБ, а в сжатом 6ГБ. Сама база тоже до минимум шринканута. В таблице для всех строк требуется сделать апдейт одного столбца (тип integer). Данный столбец не включен ни в один из индексов. При обновлении данного столбца update table1 set col10=randint() база данных начинает сильно разрастаться. При этом система показывает что и в лог файле и в самой базе есть свободное место и не мало. Больше 30%. Вопрос почему скл не использует это свободное место, а увеличивает для этого текущую базу? Что он записывает при обновлении в базу данных, то есть за счет каких данных она растет? И как прогнозировать рост базы данных в таком случае?

Comment: Думаю это поможет https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5829/update-statement-performance-in-sql-server/

Comment: Растет из-за журнала транзакции. Который получается по разному от способа изменений в базу данных. В статье которую я указал есть и про это

Comment: На счёт размеров логов вам нужно почитать структуры данных и как они хранятся. Вам будет понятно почему в структурах много дыр

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Я использовал методику удаления данных порциями. Тут почему-то упустил этот момент с обновлением. Но все равно это не могу понять, почему так сильно увеличвается mdf файл? Понимаю, что лог файл должен расти.

Comment: Там указаны почему на балк нужен большой лог

Comment: Так с логом как раз вопросов меньше всего. Было не понимание на счет .mdf

Comment: Ну то что поле не находится в индексе. Это только ваше видение. На самом деле в первичном ключе находятся все поля.

Comment: A Primary Index (PI) is the physical mechanism for assigning a data row. Всю запись т.е. все поля

Comment: На счёт mdf. Он как известно растет скачками. Так к слову

Comment: Я конечно предполагаю но мне кажется что сервер сам бронирует пространство что не было проблем с операцией которая не маленькая как бы ни казалась

Comment: Вот ещё статейка https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-determine-free-space-and-file-size-for-sql-server-databases/

Comment: Подозреваю что в MDF файл копируются разархивированные и обновленные строки таблицы, поэтому этот файл рос.

Comment: Вообще-то конечно программирование бд и администрирование это различные задачи которые собственно выполняются разными людьми. Но знания лишними не бывают